# External HDD makes clicking sound only when transferring lots of small files

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, clicking-sound

Recently, I bought an external HDD from Toshiba and used it for backing up files from my computers. Yesterday I was copying data from an old laptop (with underpowered USB, I think) and the HDD often (like 15-20 times) was turned off with a hard 'click' sound. Now, when accessing files on the drive, I can hear (and feel) slight grinding and also my HDD makes a light clicking sound *only* when transferring lots of small files (is that normal?)

Should I be worried? Thank you

**edit**

I tested the drive using SeaTools, CrystalDiskInfo, wmic (`diskdrive get status`) and chkdsk, and every test turned OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you should be worried.**

Your harddrive most likely has a physical defect which is causing the noise and it is on it's way to fail entirely. Stop using the harddrive for file storage and backup any files while you still can.

The hard click sound you heard while it turned off is probably the heads slamming back in place and there's a good chance that they got misaligned in the process, which is why you're now hearing a grinding sound. (this is just a guess, really, you can only be 100% sure by opening it)

The only sounds that you should be able to hear during normal operation is a slight hum and maybe the rapid movement of the heads. Ticking, grinding, etc. are telltale sounds of impending doom.

I'm afraid there's really nothing you can do, though you might be able to see if you can get it falls under warranty seeing how you said that you only just got it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll back up my files and try to replace my HDD, I hope the warranty covers it